# Is it possible for triggers not to fire?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

On three different tables I have separate `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` triggers.

I know positively that they work as expected (tried adding, deleting, updating and confirmed the changes going to log-table). However, it happens that rows are removed or added, without my log tables having any content.

So my question is: Is it possible for instance to add a record without the enabled INSERT trigger being triggered?

This is on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Is it possible that multiple records are inserted/deleted in a single statement? I think a trigger will only fire once in those situations in SQL Server

Comment: A common source for this question is when it turns out you've written your triggers to only cope with a single row in `inserted` or `deleted` (e.g. doing `select @var = col from inserted`), and then multi-row statements only log *one* row from the trigger. Can you show one of your triggers?

Comment: it is certainly possible, but there is always a reason (settings not turned on, record locks, syntax in code, etc). Can you provide your code and some context to help clue us in as to what your particular issue might be?

Comment: If you use any logic in you trigger then possible everything;)trigger please

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if queries were executed that disable the use of a particular trigger, e.g. by using

```
DISABLE TRIGGER { [ schema_name . ] trigger_name [ ,...n ] | ALL }
ON { object_name | DATABASE | ALL SERVER } [ ; ]
```

Also, as Damien pointed out, in may cases your trigger may only work on single records.
Wrong (simplyfied example:

```
    UPDATE table SET field = value WHERE PK = (SELECT PK FROM inserted)
```

Better:

```
    UPDATE table SET field = value WHERE PK IN (SELECT PK FROM inserted)
```

Show us your trigger, and we'll figure it out.